# Squid Reverse Proxy And Apache On The Same Server

Tags: apache, port, reverse-proxy, squid

My website server running Apache 2 is on the same physical server as my Squid 3 reverse proxy server. Everything is working fine, but for one big problem.

Crucial information:

1. Ip address of that server is 80.241.222.150
2. Squid 3 reverse proxy port is set up at port 80
3. Apache 2 web server is set up at port 8080

When calling website directly with backslash, everything is fine. Example: http://www.megasity.com/newsharvester/

But when calling the same URL without a backslash:
http://www.megasity.com/newsharvester

Website doesn't load and returns a error of non existing website and in browser. You will see domain name with port attached to it. Result is http://www.megasity.com:8080/newsharvester/

I already tried few things with .htaccess, but I'm missing something, or the problem lies somewhere else. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to  force a trailing slash using .htaccess even if someone visits the page without the "end" slash. Try the following.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```